# Automatic pagination in google-cloud-node

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-node

The [datastore nodejs docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#cursors_limits_and_offsets) mention that the client library will do automatic pagination by default:

> By default, google-cloud-node will automatically paginate through all
>   of  the results that match a query. However, this sample implements
>   manual  pagination using limits and cursor tokens.

What is an example of automatic pagination?

Answer (score 2):

Automatic Pagination, in this context, really means that the API would retrieve all results that match your query. By setting a limit and start cursor you limit the number of rows returned to a specific page. The example sets a limit of 5 rows, and uses a start cursor, so your results never exceed more than 5 entities. If you exclude the limit and start cursor (calls to the respective methods), you would get all the results.